# VirtualBox dynamic storage

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

I am using virtual box 5.1 and have created a virtual machine with 8 Gb of dynamic storage. It's initial size is showing 2 Mb. My question is that when the space utilisation reaches 8Gb , will it expand more than 8 gb dynamically or not ?

Comment: No, it will not. The upper limit prevents the application from hogging up all of your disk space. If you are not worried about that, just build a large disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not expand beyond the original amount you allocated for it.

From [virtualbox.org/manual/ch05.html](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch05.html)

> For more flexible storage management, use a dynamically allocated
>   image. This will initially be very small and not occupy any space for
>   unused virtual disk sectors, but will grow every time a disk sector is
>   written to for the first time, **until the drive reaches the maximum
>   capacity chosen when the drive was created.**